# Every new solution I open has missing References

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

Anytime I open a downloaded project, the References for all the default XNA stuff is missing, and I have to manually re-add it. It is really annoying to do so for each one.

I get this warning for all the default Microsoft.Xna.Framework references:

```
Warning 50  The referenced component 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact' could not be found.
```

Is there a way to change the default location to something correct, or maybe to automatically relink those?

Comment: do you have the 'wrong' (i.e. incompatible) version of XNA installed?

Comment: No, I had the latest version installed. But I reinstalled it, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're trying to refernce a DLL that was downloaded from the Web. In such cases, unless you *unblock* the dll, it won't be usable, and therefor VS would give you this error message.

This is a feature of Window 7 AFAIK, which if for security reasons. it's not VS's fault but Windows'.

usually what you have to do is just Right-Click the dll in windows explorer, select properties, and click **unblock**.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I just reinstalled and its now working.

Comment: Re-install, the way to debug through life... :D